# Python changes variable/timezone while running?

Tags: python, timezone, icalendar

Ok, this is one of the weirdest bugs I've encountered!

First: I'm not a Python programmer, and the script is written by friend (who I think took most of it from an example).

**The purpose of the script:** To parse calendar info (times in CET) from a XML-file to an ics-file, so people can add it to their Google calendars etc (the files are continuously updated).

**The problem I tried to fix:** Make it import into Google calendar correctly (with correct times etc)

**What I did:** Changed the time conversion to include timezones.

**The weird problem:** While executing, the timezone changes from CET to CEST (at the same event so far as I can see). The variable that holds the timezone is only assigned once (before the loop that goes through the events), so I can't for my life figure out what's causing the problem!

**Piece of the output:**

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Ungdomsaktivitet
DTSTART;TZID=CET;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150327T193000
DTEND;TZID=CET;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150327T193000
LOCATION:Kaj
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Ungdomsmöte
DTSTART;TZID=CET;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150328T193000
DTEND;TZID=CET;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150328T193000
DESCRIPTION:Ekumeniskt ungdomsmöte mellan Skara\, Götene & Lidköping. S
 amuel Östersjö predikar\, Elias Olofsson med team leder lovsång.
LOCATION:Pingstkyrkan\, Lidköping
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Bön
DTSTART;TZID=CEST;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150329T100000
DTEND;TZID=CEST;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150329T100000
LOCATION:Pingstkyrkan\, Lidköping
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Gudstjänst
DTSTART;TZID=CEST;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150329T110000
DTEND;TZID=CEST;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150329T110000
DESCRIPTION:Evangelicenter
LOCATION:Pingstkyrkan\, Lidköping
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Ekumenisk bön
DTSTART;TZID=CEST;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150331T100000
DTEND;TZID=CEST;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20150331T100000
DESCRIPTION:i Baptistkyrkan
LOCATION:Baptistkyrkan\, Lidköping
END:VEVENT
```

**The code that deals with the times:**

```
lt = LocalTimezone()

# [...]

d = datetime.strptime(dateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
t = datetime.strptime(timeStr, "%H:%M:%S").time()
event.add('dtstart', datetime.combine(d,t).replace(tzinfo=lt))
event.add('dtend', datetime.combine(d,t).replace(tzinfo=lt))
```

**The full code:** http://pastebin.com/Gf68BWc2

I'm glad for all the ideas I can get on how to fix this!

Comment: Don't use `LocalTimezone()`; it is based on `time` module and therefore may fail in some timezones. [Use `tzlocal.get_localzone()`instead.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal)

Comment: unrelated: some calendar libraries are inherently buggy and expect that all datetime objects are in UTC even if you pass an aware datetime object (with an attached timezone). Convert  to/from UTC if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `lt` is a [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) timezone, then you probably need to change your code from this:

```
datetime.combine(d,t).replace(tzinfo=lt)
```

To this:

```
lt.localize(datetime.combine(d,t))
```

You should probably also use the [full time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (ex: `Europe/Stockholm`) instead of `CET` or `CEST`.

Also, you should be aware that [summer time begins in Europe on March 29, 2015](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/sweden/stockholm).  Since some of your dates are before the change, and some are after, you will indeed have some in CET and some in CEST.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that CET is ambiguous e.g., `Europe/Kaliningrad` is different from `Europe/Warsaw`

Comment: Thank you, now that part works correctly!
Yeah, I forgot about DST. The times from the source is (mostly) the same every week and simple export to XML as a "timestamp/string". So no part of the "chain" cares about DST etc..

Now I just need to figure out why Google calendar first imports the times correctly, but then they disappear..